# BMI calculator. Trying to make a loop that prints who's overweight, underweight, normal, and obese. Getting a function error

Tags: python

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
heights = []
weights = []
for recipient in recipients:
  heights.append(int(input("What is your height " + recipient )))
  weights.append(int(input("What is your weight " + recipient )))

def BMI(weights, heights):
  for weight, height in zip(weights, heights):
    bmi_total = (weight * 703) / (height ** 2)
    print(bmi_total)

BMI(weights, heights)

BMI_calc = []

BMI_calc.append(BMI)

for BMI in BMI_calc:
  print(BMI)

def index(BMI):
  if BMI <= 18.5:
    print("Your BMI is', BMI, 'You are underweight.")

  elif BMI > 18.5 and BMI < 24.9:
    print("You're normal weight.")

  elif BMI > 25 and BMI < 29.9:
    print("You're overweight.")

  elif BMI > 30:
    print("You're obese.")
```

My instructions for this calculator after discovering their BMI with the math formula function are:

That body mass index should then be appended to an array. Using a second loop it should traverse the array of body mass indices and call another function that accepts the body mass index as a parameter and returns whether the individual is underweight, normal weight or overweight.

The output/error is:

```
What is your height John70
What is your weight John176
What is your height Dee65
What is your weight Dee167
What is your height Aleister80
What is your weight Aleister180
What is your height Lilith55
What is your weight Lilith123
What is your height Paul89
What is your weight Paul200
What is your height Reggy65
What is your weight Reggy164
25.250612244897958
27.78721893491124
19.771875
28.584793388429752
17.750284055043554
27.28804733727811
<function BMI at 0x00000249AED283A0>
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the name `BMI` for both a function and a numerical value.

Comment: This appends the function, not the results: `BMI_calc.append(BMI)`. In general, you will have an easier time if you make a function that calculates a *single* BMI and *returns* a single result rather than one that takes lists and is also responsible to printing..

Answer (score -1):

> hi
> I change your code a little and I wrote it with dictionary and at the end of the code
> it prints the name and result of BMI for each person.
> one of your problems was the function output, you didn't return anything and then you want to save it in variable.

this is the download link of the .py file of code :
[link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/a6zzeqiw9fs2vgt/BMI.py/file)

Goodluck

Comment: While this might answer the question, do consider that links tend to rot away. To make your answer useful to future users, please edit the code in.